# Error with AngularJS - failed to instantiate module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm going through angular for .net book and I'm using a basic example of having an app with two controllers. However I get this error now and I can't see why it would fail to instantiate module:

Unhandled exception at line 4138, column 9 in http://localhost:53990/Scripts/angular.js

```
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

**This is my code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS with .NET</title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Game setup</h1>
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController1">
        <h2>Player 1</h2>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter player 1 name" ng-model="name" ng-focus="onNameFocused()" />
        <h3 ng-show="name">Player 1 name is {{name}}</h3>
        <h3 ng-show="previousName">Previous Player 1 name was {{previousName}}</h3>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="ExampleController2">
        <h2>Player 2</h2>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter player 2 name" ng-model="name" ng-focus="onNameFocused()" />
        <h3 ng-show="name">Player 2 name is {{name}}</h3>
        <h3 ng-show="previousName">Previous Player 2 name was {{previousName}}</h3>
    </div>

    <script>
        (function () {
            "use strict"
            var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
            //myAppModule.filter('customname', function () {
            //    return function (name) {
            //        name = name || '';
            //        var customName = "";
            //        for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            //            if (name.charAt(i) == "e") {
            //                customName += "3";
            //            }
            //            else if (name.charAt(i) == "o") {
            //                customName += "0"
            //            }
            //            else {
            //                customName += name.charAt(i);
            //            }
            //        }
            //        return customName;
            //    }
            //})

            myAppModule.controller('ExampleController1', ['$scope', function
                ($scope) { // Explicit dependency injection
                $scope.name = "Alex Pop";
                $scope.previousName = "";
                $scope.onNameFocused = function () {
                    $scope.previousName = $scope.name;
                };
            }]);

            myAppModule.controller('ExampleController2', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.name = "Alex Pop";
                $scope.previousName = "";
                $scope.onNameFocused = function () {
                    $scope.previousName = $scope.name;
                };
            }]);
            console.log(myAppModule.name);
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with it?

Comment: you defined your angular script as an IIFE, but never invoked it with `()` at the end.  either unwrap it, or invoke it.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: @Claies I didn't know I needed another () to invoke it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrapped your entire Angular Script in an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), but you never invoked the function to load the script.

```
(function () {
...
});
```

You either should unwrap the function, or invoke the function, like so:

```
(function () {
...
}());
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I'll make your answer as correct when SO lets me.